# Why the Qt-made GUI gets stuck with time?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, qt, user-interface

When just loaded, the app is fairly smooth, however with time passing by, the gui gets slower and slower, which is, when i click a button, it will only take effect after a few seconds(1 or 2).

I have watched the process in task-manager, the memory usage is stable(around 5m), and before i click the buttons, the cpu usage is also 0.

I am using Qt_4.8.0 with visual_studio_2010.

Is it because of the efficiency of qt lib on windows?

Some code:
/////////mainwindow.h////////////

```
QPushButton* reloadHostsPushButton = new QPushButton("Reload Hosts");
reloadHostsPushButton->setMaximumSize(aPushButtonMaxSize);
connect(reloadHostsPushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
        this, SLOT(reloadHostsClicked()));

QPushButton* flushDNSPushButton = new QPushButton("Flush DNS Cache");
flushDNSPushButton->setMaximumSize(aPushButtonMaxSize);
connect(flushDNSPushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
        this, SLOT(flushDNSClicked()));

controlPanelLayout = new QGridLayout();
controlPanelLayout->addWidget(openHostsPushButton, 0, 0);
controlPanelLayout->addWidget(reloadHostsPushButton, 0, 1);
controlPanelLayout->addWidget(flushDNSPushButton, 0, 2);
controlPanelLayout->addWidget(quitPushButton, 1, 2);
controlPanelLayout->addWidget(aboutPushButton, 1, 1);
controlPanelLayout->addWidget(optionsPushButton, 1, 0);

controlPanel = new QWidget();
controlPanel->setLayout(controlPanelLayout);
```

/////////server.h//////////////flushDNSClicked() calls this/////////

```
void Server::flushDNSCache(){
    ui_LogPanel->log("Flushing DNS cache...", UI_LogPanel::aLogRed);
    QProcess* tmp = new QProcess();
    tmp->start("ipconfig", QStringList() << "/flushdns");
    ui_LogPanel->log("DNS cache flushed!", UI_LogPanel::aLogItalic | UI_LogPanel::aLogGreen);
}
```

Comment: any example code to reproduce?

Comment: there must be something else wrong. can you post your code?

Comment: Maybe it is because you are running code in using the same thread with the user interface. This will make the application look like is not responding until your code behind the button is executed.

Comment: @KamilKlimek it's a project with a lot of codes, i posted some of the concerned code.

Comment: @marcushatchenson `QProcess::start()` says it will create a new process.

Comment: Well... then you should strip your code to get only "problematic" part of code. First of all... you know, that when QProcess finishes its work it won't delete itself? Also process did not even start after start call

Comment: What is ui_LogPanel? Maybe it is problematic part? How does it append logs? Only a wild gues, but probably it is some kind of QTextEdit/QTextBrowser?

Comment: Qt is used by many projects on Windows without this problem, so the bug is almost definitely in your code.  As Marcus said, chances are that the main UI thread is occupied doing something so it is slow responding to mouse clicks.  Try using a profiler (the AMD one is free http://developer.amd.com/tools/AMDAPPProfiler/Pages/default.aspx) or even just hit the Pause button in the debugger a few times to see what it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flushDNSCache() slot function contains a bug and some wishful thinking. Although I don't think that it will cause the slowdown.

You are creating a QProcess object but you are never deleting it. And you are printing to the log that the DNS cache is flushed, wishing that everything went okay.

If you don't care whether the ipconfig succeeded, you can use [QProcess::startDetached](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#startDetached-2) as follows:

```
void Server::flushDNSCache(){
    ui_LogPanel->log("Flushing DNS cache...", UI_LogPanel::aLogRed);
    QProcess::startDetached("ipconfig", QStringList() << "/flushdns");
    ui_LogPanel->log("DNS cache flushed!", 
        UI_LogPanel::aLogItalic | UI_LogPanel::aLogGreen);
}
```

Now you don't leave any undeleted QProcess objects hanging around.

Even better would be to use [QProcess::execute](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#execute):

```
void Server::flushDNSCache(){
    ui_LogPanel->log("Flushing DNS cache...", UI_LogPanel::aLogRed);
    int exitCode = QProcess::execute("ipconfig", QStringList() << "/flushdns");
    if (exitCode == 0)
    {
        ui_LogPanel->log(
            "DNS cache flushed!", 
            UI_LogPanel::aLogItalic | UI_LogPanel::aLogGreen);
    }
    else
    {
        ui_LogPanel->log(
            QString("DNS cache flush failed with exit code %1!").arg(exitCode), 
            UI_LogPanel::aLogItalic | UI_LogPanel::aLogRed);
    }
}
```

Now you can check the exit code. Note however, that the QProcess::execute will wait until the process finishes so if you start long running process your application will freeze until the process finishes.

Answer (score 0):

can you try `delete`ing tmp? but, probably it's caused by another part of your code. we can review it if you post more.

As the_mandrill stated, [many projects](http://qt.nokia.com/qt-in-use) (like VLC, Skype...) are using Qt without problems.